# Illogical HTML and CSS inheritance?

Tags: html, css, inheritance, behavior

I have a footer table which always has to stay at the bottom. In order to achieve this I have made a div with a class wrapper. wrappers height and width are 100%. The footer is not inside the wrapper so it is always at the bottom. By giving the wrapper a margin bottom of -150px I pull the footer up. However when you re size the page it becomes evident that the the table inside wrapper inherited the margin bottom -150px which is strange. If I do set margin bottom 150px for the table it stops working in safari and chrome.

Here is the site: http://canmill.zxq.net

Help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing what the problem is. On Chrome 13/Windows 7, it doesn't look like any new margins are introduced anywhere. Can you post before/after images?

Comment: The problem is there. Just turns out I uploaded wrong file. But now its the correct one and its buggy

Comment: give the wrapper a padding-bottom of 1px. That should prevent margin-collapse.

Comment: It is there, I uploaded wrong file again

Comment: the padding bottom didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few design choices (specifically your wrapping divs) which have contributed to the problem. The code provided on this page should help you correct it: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html

Comment: Very helpful link thanks, If I had seen something like this before making the site it would have been very helpful +1 for that

Comment: Adapting your site to use this format wouldn't be too difficult, though. From the looks of it your header and footer are a static height and your content is a variable height. So just adapt your layout to the "Sticky Footer" layout by putting your header in the top of the #wrap block, your content in the #main block, and your footer in the #footer block.

Comment: That is in fact what I'm currently doing :)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
.wrapper {
  padding: 0 0 200px 0;
}

.footer {
  margin-top: 0px;
  background: url(images/bottombg.jpg) repeat-x;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```